# Awk variable passing question

Tags: bash, scripts, awk

This is the code I wrote to resolve DNSs and output to a file. Is there a way to forgo the `while` loop entirely and just write in `awk`? It works perfectly but it seems very cumbersome and inefficient, takes about 10 mins for 25k lines of IPs. Will gladly elaborate on script if clarity is needed.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
  echo -en " ${startCount} / ${endCount} IPs resolved\r"
  ip=$(echo ${line} | cut -d "," -f1)
  col2=$(nslookup ${ip} | fgrep "name" | sed -e 's/\t/,/g' -e 's/name = //g' -e 's/.uncc.edu.//g' | cut -d "," -f2)
  if [[ ! -z ${col2} ]]; then
    echo "${line}" | awk -F"," -v var="${col2}" '{print $1","var","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}' >> ${outFile}
  else
    echo "${line}" | awk -F"," '{print $1",""UNRESOLVED"","$2","$3","$4","$5","$6}' >> ${outFile}
  fi
  ((startCount++))
done < ${1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
gawk -F, '
    # spawns nslookup as a coprocess, passes the IP into its stdin
    # then reads the output of the coprocess to find the hostname
    function get_name(ip,      line, name) { 
        name = "UNRESOLVED"
        print ip |& "nslookup"
        close("nslookup", "to")
        while (("nslookup" |& getline line) > 0) {
            if (match(/name =(.+)\.uncc\.edu\./, line, m)) 
                name = m[1]
        }
        close("nslookup")
        return name
    }
    { print $1, get_name($1), $2, $3, $4, $5, $6 }
' "$1" > "$outfile"
```

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html

Comment: Consider not using a coprocess: `command = "nslookup "ip; while ((command | getline line) > 0) { .... }; close (command)`.